# apache DBD not connecting to MySQL

Tags: mysql, debian, apache-2.4, authentication

I use mod_dbd and mod_authn_dbd to secure access to my websites. But it seems to be instable, few minutes after restarting apache and some requests made, authentication does not work anymore with this message in apache error log:

```
[authn_dbd:error] [pid 21308] [client xxxxx] AH01656: Query execution error looking up 'mylogin' in database []
```

**Edit apache log with more details:**

```
[authz_core:debug] [pid 9307] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client x.x.x.x] AH01626: authorization result of Require dbd-group mygroup: denied (no authenticated user yet)
[authn_dbd:error] [pid 9307] [client x.x.x.x] AH01656: Query execution error looking up 'mylogin' in database []
[core:trace3] [pid 9307] request.c(119): [client x.x.x.x] auth phase 'check user' gave status 500: /private
```

and in mysql error log:

```
[Note] Aborted connection 5000 to db: 'httpauthdb' user: 'httpauth' host: 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' (Got an error reading communication packets)
```

I have to restart apache to make it work but not for a long time. I have found out that setting DBDPersist (in dbd conf) to Off solve my problem but it is not recommended to do so according to apache documentation.

**Edit**: Querying the same database with mysql client works, even after error occurs.

Here a piece of configuration in a vhost:

```
<Location /private>
  AuthName 'My private space'
  AuthType Basic
  AuthBasicProvider dbd
  AuthDBDUserPWQuery "SELECT password FROM clients WHERE username = %s"
  AuthzDBDQuery "SELECT groups FROM clients WHERE username = %s"
  Require dbd-group mygroup
</Location>
```

Here my dbd_mysql.conf loaded by apache

```
DBDriver mysql
DBDParams "sock=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock,user=httpauth,dbname=httpauthdb,pass=xxxxxxxx"
DBDMin  4
DBDKeep 2
DBDMax  10
DBDExptime 300
DBDPersist On
```

The result of apachectl -V:

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian)
Server built:   2017-01-25T22:59:26
Server's Module Magic Number: 20120211:67
Server loaded:  APR 1.5.1, APR-UTIL 1.5.4
Compiled using: APR 1.5.2, APR-UTIL 1.5.4
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     prefork
  threaded:     no
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=256
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/apache2"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/lib/apache2/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/var/run/apache2.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="apache2.conf"
```

and mysql version:

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.17-13, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using  6.3
```

Any ideas on where the problem come from ?

Comment: When the issue occurs, can you please try to log in to mysql and try any query before restarting anything? Would you edit question providing this detail too?

Comment: @Marco There is no problem with mysql. Right now i think that maybe it's mod_dbd who fail to properly set the persistence connection to mysql. but why ?

Comment: How about changing apache's log level to debug or trace?

Comment: I have edited my post, but it is not a really useful information...

Comment: I'm going to upgrade to Debian 9, we'll see if the problem persists

Comment: I upgraded a system to Centos8 and get similar behavior with mod_authn_dbd. Queries work 95% of the time but the other 5% I get internal server errors. I was thinking that perhaps there was some delay between the server containing the mysql db that I was authenticating against and the webserver, so I cloned the mysql db onto the webserver locally but still get the same issue. Before upgrading I was running Centos 6 with apache2.4 and I did not receive this error.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I'd like to say that setting

DBDPersist Off

Resolved the issue to me.

Answer (score 0):

For us, this problem seems to happen because Apache doesn't properly realize that persisted MySQL connections have timed out from long waits. It *should* simply open a new connection but I guess it doesn't.

A better fix than simply disabling DBDPersist seems to be to reduce the DBDExptime to a value lower than MySQL's wait timeout.